# Adding CSS Class/ID to display a section in one page at a different page (Elementor / Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

im using elementor to create my website .
I have a section (Size Guide) on a single page  which I would like to display at each single product page. How do i go by doing it ?

[size guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Oj0u.png)
[page to add the size guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSb5q.png)

Answer (score 0):

First, you create one template of the section which you want to display on each single product page.
Then go to a particular page where you want to display the section. and click on add template [image]

then click on my template and select the section which you want to add and insert it

Comment: The problem is i want to apply it as an element inside an accordion , therefore a template will not work since templates work with sections and columns.

Comment: Then, with the use of tabs, you may find sections that are relevant to you.

Comment: Got it ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered

- creating your size guide via templates > new > template type: section
- then from templates > saved templates, copy the shortcode for your size guide
- navigate to your accordion and paste in your shortcode

Everything should be good when you then preview the page